# duda contenedor flexible y align-self-start

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, flexbox

Tengo un row que toma por altura 100%, el problema que tengo es al usar "align-items-start" me deja margenes entre los elementos "col" en vez de pegarmelos, el primer col lo posiciona bien, pero queda un margen con el segundo. Pense en ponerle "d-block" y funciona, pero necesito que el contenedor sea flex.

Edit: 
Tengo esto ...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero lograr...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edit 2:

Bueno ya lo solucione, estaba usando la propiedad erronea, align-items deja margenes en altura entre elementos, solucione el asunto con align-content.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Flex</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="height: 100vh;">
    <div class="row bg-warning h-100 align-content-start">
      <div class="col-12 bg-danger">
        <span>COLUMNA1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 bg-info">
        <span>COLUMNA2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yo lo veo bien, ¿podrías poner una imagen de cómo lo ves y el resultado esperado?

Comment: Pues yo veo un margen entre el primer col y el segundo, que raro

Comment: En qué browser lo estás viendo? Qué versión tenés? Sistema operativo?

Comment: Firefox y Chrome, pero ya edite el post con la solucion

Comment: @Kleith ¿qué tiene que ver el sistema operativo con la pregunta?

Comment: @EMCode porque si es IE, existe cierta limitación en las versiones de SO, y en MacOS anteriormente también con Safari para windows (pero ya no existe más), también infiere para las versiones mobile.

Comment: @dav1c1n Me alegra que encontraras la solución al problema. No pongas la solución en la pregunta, ponla en la sección de respuestas para que la publicación quede completa y otros usuarios puedan encontrarla de forma más sencilla. Lee [answer] para más información.